# iptables -I INPUT -p TCP -j ACCEPT

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

```
iptables -I INPUT -p TCP -j ACCEPT
```

Is executing the above command would increase security risks on the Centos 7 server?
And how to roll back that command?

Is below command okay for rolling back above command?

```
iptables -D INPUT -p TCP -j ACCEPT
```

and what does this do?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me try to figure that out...

### is this rule a good idea

```
iptables -I INPUT -p TCP -j ACCEPT
```

actually means, that your machine will accept any TCP connection regardless of where it comes from and what local port it goes to. Do **not** do that. Only open your local machine based on ports/services that you **want** to provide a service for and that you want to be open to the outside.
As an example, if you had a web server running and wanted anybody from outside to be able to access it usering `https` you would be issuing something like

```
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport https --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Let me walk you through that...

- `A input` means: add it to the input table. Note: instead of inserting, the rule is appended to the INPUT table. It is expected that the default policy for INPUT is drop and there is no rule before ours that would drop packets unconditionally.
- `-p TCP` means: for the TCP protocol
- `--dport https` means: if the connection is made to our local port 443
- `--syn` means: if the packet arriving is the first packet of a TCP connection, aka. someone is actually trying to make a connection for real
- `-m conntrack` means: remember the connection once it's established so we can allow any further packets that arrive and belong to that connection
- `--ctstate NEW` means: evaluate the connection state and if the connection is new, accept it (this is more sophisticated than `--syn` but basically uses the same mechanism)
- `-j ACCEPT` means: accept the packet if all of the above is fulfilled

For the connection tracking to work (`-m conntrack`), you would need a rule like

`iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

probably as your first rule in your INPUT table. This allows packets for any connection, that we have successfully established to pass the firewall.

### can you revert it that way

No, you can't. When using iptables and you want to remove a rule, `iptables -D chain` is your way to go. The rule you actually want to remove must be provided by number. You may obtain that number by providing `--line-numbers` to iptables as in

`iptables -vnL --line-numbers`

which may produce an output like

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 11379 packets, 2225K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     121M  340G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2     552K   39M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3      161 13182 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
4        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
6        0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:113 flags:0x17/0x02 reject-with tcp-reset
7        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 flags:0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 15618 packets, 1630K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

The *num* column shows you the number to pass to `iptables -D`. Just don't forget to pass the chain's name, too.

<sup><sub>For the record: yes, that's my setup with a lot of docker stuff stripped :-).</sub></sup>

Comment: i have csf configserver firewall and i also restarted the webmin , was it reverted back?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't tell. Most linux distros have a script, that saves the rules upon system halt/reboot and loads them back again on boot. Afaik webmin is only some PHP front-end that also allows accessing iptables. Restarting that should not change anything, as the firewall rules are stored in kernel memory.

Comment: To get an idea of the basic concepts, I'd advise to work through [Linux 2.4 Packet Filtering HOWTO](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO.html). Please note, that `iptables` has been superseded by `nftables`, so you might as well dive into that.
If your original question has been answered sufficiently, could you accept it, so it does not show up as open to others? Thank you!